# BIDS for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, bids

Does anyone know if/when the BIDS add-on will be available for VS2015?  It's the only thing holding us back from migrating.  Or is there  different method for building SSRS reports in VS2015?

Update:  Our code solutions typically consist of multiple projects - code/dal, frontend, database, reporting, etc.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but "[BIDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Intelligence_Development_Studio)" is discontinued in favor of SQL Server Data Tools. SQL Server Data Tools is just an option you can check when installing Visual Studio 2015, but can be downloaded separately [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501).

Comment: Yes, but it does not migrate existing reporting projects.  There is no option to create a reporting project either - just a reporting application which fires up a winforms app with a report viewer window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100 sure but I think they have released it but its still in preview
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

> [Download the Latest SSDT Preview for Visual Studio 2015](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=620916)
>
> Provides the unified template collection for relational database
>   development, SSAS data models, SSRS reports, and SSIS packages.

Answer (score 6):

It's now know as SQL Server Data Tools and is accessible via your Tools option in Visual Studio 2015

Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates -> Microsoft SQL Server Update for Database.

Comment: The BI portion isn't released yet unfortunately.  I just installed VS2015 on a new dev box with SSDT, but reporting is still not available.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I've managed to dig up (thanks to a friend): https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ea9c0360-d4f4-480e-b022-52b9d9189c51/visual-studio-2015-ssis-development-backward-compatibility-can-we-develop-2008-2012-2014?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Looks like I'm stuck waiting to migrate to VS2015 until SSDT-BI is released for VS2015

Answer (score 1):

SSDT is updated on July 7 2016, can be downloaded from Microsoft website  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx